# Self signed certificate in certificate chain while yarn install

Tags: node.js, npm, yarnpkg, node-sass, yarn-v2

Unable to do yarn install -lock file getting following error.

```
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Fetch Error: request to https://nodejs.org/download/release/v16.14
.0/node-v16.14.0-headers.tar.gz failed, reason: self signed certificate in certificate chain
gyp ERR! stack     at Client Request.\<anonymous\> 
gyp ERR! stack     at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:520:28)
gyp ERR! stack     at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (node:\_http_client:442:9)
gyp ERR! stack     at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:520:28)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:157:8)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:122:3)
gyp ERR! stack     at process`your text`TicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queu
es:83:21)
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" 
p\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags="
"--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
gyp ERR! node -v v16.14.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v8.4.1
```

unable to do yarn install , While doing so getting error in node module related to self signed certificate which is not sure why its happening so .